# How to accept an input date from the user using HTML/JavaScript in Dynamics 365?

Tags: javascript, html, dynamics-crm

I have a HTML webform that is trying to accept user input such as their address, card number, city, and state, etc as a text. However, in Microsoft Dynamics 365, I have a custom entity containing those fields such that when the user enters the data on the HTML webform and submits it, a record gets created within the custom entity in the CRM database.

However, in my CRM, I have fields, expiration and expiration_date as a Date value. In my HTML file, I have them as accepting a month as input (month and year as input). Whenever I input a month and year, and submit the form, I get a CRM error indicating the date is null.

For reference here's the code I'm talking about:

```js
entity.new_expirationdate= document.getElementById('new_expirationdate').value;
entity.new_expiration = document.getElementById('new_expiration').value;
```

```html
Expiration Date: <input type="month" name="Expiration Date" id="new_expirationdate"><br>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are planning to store `Month` & `Year` separately, then the fields should be of `Whole Number` type to store `Integer` values.

`Date and Time` type field cannot be used to store your `Month` or `Year` values.

[Learn more about CRM field types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customer-engagement/customize/types-of-fields)

Comment: I have re-created the field with your suggestion. However, I still get a CRM script error.

Comment: @KRamakrishnan pls edit the question, add the exact error & full code + mention the line you are getting error.

Comment: The record gets successfully created this time. I'm not sure if it's a time out error or not, but what it doesn't show is the expiration date in both Month and Year (that's what the month input in HTML contains). Instead in my CRM, it shows just a blank.